# Which of the Ruby libraries/wrappers for the Stack Exchange API is most complete?

Tags: discussion, ruby

There seem to be a number of Ruby libraries: [Pilha](https://github.com/dlt/pilha) or [Rubyoverflow](https://github.com/phsr/rubyoverflow). Has anyone used either of these? What are their strengths and weaknesses? Which is more actively maintained?

Comment: Don't know if this helps or not, but the latest commit for Pilha was on April 21, 2011 whereas the latest commit for Rubyoverflow was on July 18, 2010. So it looks like Pilha is still maintained to a certain degree.

Comment: @GeorgeEdison While that might be true, Pilha doesn't support anything other than SO.

Answer (score 2):

Rubyoverflow dev here, I've been rewriting it recently.  I'm actually going to be redoing it again now, seeing that the 2.0 beta is out.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest [Serel](http://serel.tom.is/). This is much better and complete as compared to pilha and rubyoverflow.`